# Display custom meta on page that has been check in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, front-end

I have created a custom post type (cpt) and within each post type is a custom meta field.

This custom meta field displays all the pages that can 'checked'.

Code to generate the custom meta box:

```
// display list of pages with check box
function page_meta_box( $post ) {

// Nonce to verify intention later
wp_nonce_field( 'save_quote_meta', 'custom_nonce' ); 

 // we store data as an array, we need to unserialize it
$checkfield = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'checkfieldBox', true) );

$pages = get_pages(); 
foreach ( $pages as $page )
{ ?>
    <input id="page_<?php echo $page->ID; ?>" type="checkbox" name="checkfield[]" value="<?php echo $page->ID; ?>"
    <?php if ( in_array($page->ID, $checkfield) ) { ?>checked="checked" <?php } ?>/>
          <label for="page_<?php echo $page->ID; ?>"><?php echo  $page->post_title; ?></label><br>
<?php 
    } 
}
```

Code to save the custom meta box values:

```
//save the meta box action
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_meta_save', 10, 2 );
//save the meta box
function myplugin_meta_save($post_id, $post)
{

  if ( isset($_POST['checkfield']) ) { // if we get new data
     update_post_meta($post_id, 'checkfieldBox', $_POST['checkfield'] );
  }
}
```

The query I am using to display the custom post types on the front end:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => 'sidebar_boxes',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
                'order' => 'ASC'
            ) );

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="sidebarBox floatLeft">
            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail())
            { ?>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
            <?php
            } ?>
            <div class="sideBoxText">
                <?php // Content here ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php 
endwhile;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The above code displays the CPTs with no problems.

My issue is how do I display the custom post type on the page that has been checked. Currently they are all appearing.

E.g. If I check the 'about' page on the CPT page in the dashboard, how can I display that information on the about page (front end)

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: As a sidenote, you shouldn't need `maybe_unserialize()` because passing `true` to the `get_post_meta()` function will already unserialize any serialized data. [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) runs [`get_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/) and if passed bool **true** will also run `maybe_unserialize()`

Comment: Thank you. I must admin i've never seen `maybe_serialize()` before. In face I always use `get_post_meta`.

Answer (score 1):

You just want a `meta_query` based on the current page's ID:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
  array(
    'post_type' => 'sidebar_boxes',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
      'key' => 'checkfieldBox',
      'value' => $post->ID,
    )
  ) 
);
```

You can really only depend upon `$post` in the way I did on "singular" pages and only if the the `$post` object hasn't been altered by code on the page. If you have trouble you will need to use:

```
$post_obj = get_queried_object();
// now use $post_obj->ID instead of $post->ID
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you possibly point me in the right direction on how to display the posts on the pages that have been checked?

Comment: That is exactly what I just did, but your description is confusing.